# How to copy fields from one table to another

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have searched and tried everything but have failed and was wondering if someone could help with this slightly unusual twist to copying data from one table to another.

I am collecting data from my own weather station with a piece of software written by someone else in C. I have had a look at this open source code but it is very difficult to read as it uses a lot of single character variables etc. It writes the data to a MySQL database table in a sequential format like this:-

```
CREATE TABLE readings (
    `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `name` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `value` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
)
```

Where each sensor reading is stored on a seperate row. Name denotes a sensor name such as a temperature sensor or raingauge, windspeed sensor etc, etc. All the sensors are updated every minute on the minute.
The problem I am finding is that this way of storing the data makes it extremely difficult to perform queries on it as I have to include a lot of conditionals in the query, such as checking that the 'name' field is "RGC1" for the raingauge counter etc. This really complicates things as the raingauge sensor is actually just a counter and not an instant rainfall rate. I have to perform a query on the database and subtract the previous raingauge counter value from the current one to get the number of counts between the two occasions that these were read. Each count is 0.01 inches of rainfall, so multiplying the count difference by 0.01 gives the rainfall rate as inches/interval. Temperature sensors are a little easier as they are instant temperature values but it is still complicated making comparances between different occasions.

I either need a way of calculating this data leaving the database structure as it is (which I have failed to do dismally) or to copy the new data every minute as it comes in to another database where all the sensor readings are stored on the same row, to something like this:-

```
CREATE TABLE `readings2` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `readdate` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `MS-TH-TEMP` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `MS-TH-HUM` FLOAT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `UTEMP` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `UV` FLOAT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `WSPD` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `WDIR` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `WS-TEMP` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `RGC0` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `RGC1` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `LC0` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `LC1` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `PRS0` FLOAT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `TAI8570-TEMP` FLOAT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I am running all of this on Ubuntu Server 11.04 and copying the data could be done on a cron job every minute with a ruby script or something similar.
Can anyone help? I have searched and tried a lot of suggestions from this site but have failed in my efforts to come up with a solution.

Further to my original post above, I have been doing a lot of messing around but am getting persistent syntax errors with the following code but I am damned if I can see anything wrong. If I comment out the INSERT INTO statement, the syntax error goes away. I can't see anything wrong with the syntax in the INSERT, though:-

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50033 IF EXISTS */ `copyFields`$$

CREATE TRIGGER `copyFields` AFTER UPDATE on `readings`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE mychanged INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE newDATE DATETIME DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE newMSTHTEMP FLOAT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE newMSTHHUM FLOAT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE newUTEMP FLOAT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE newUV FLOAT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE newWSPD SMALLINT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE newWDIR TINYINT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE newWSTEMP FLOAT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE newRGC0 BIGINT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE newRGC1 BIGINT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE newLC0 BIGINT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE newLC1 BIGINT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE newPRS0 FLOAT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE newTAI8570TEMP FLOAT DEFAULT NULL;
    IF NEW.name = "UTEMP" THEN
        SET mychanged = 1;
    END IF;
    IF mychanged = 1 THEN
        SET newDATE = NEW.date;
    IF NEW.name = 'MS-TH-TEMP' THEN
        SET newMSTHTEMP = NEW.value;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.name = 'MS-TH-HUM' THEN
        SET newMSTHHUM = NEW.value;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.name = 'WSPD' THEN
        SET newWSPD = NEW.value;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.name = 'WDIR' THEN
        SET newWDIR = NEW.value;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.name = 'WS-TEMP' THEN
        SET newWSTEMP = NEW.value;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.name = 'RGC0' THEN
        SET newRGC0 = NEW.value;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.name = 'RGC1' THEN
        SET newRGC1 = NEW.value;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.name = 'UTEMP' THEN
        SET newUTEMP = NEW.value;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.name = 'UV' THEN
        SET newUV = NEW.value;
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO readings2 
        (readdate,
        ms-th-temp,
        ms-th-hum,
        utemp,
        uv,
        wspd,
        wdir,
        ws-temp,
        rgc0,
        rgc1,
        lc0,
        lc1,
        prs0,
        tai8570-temp)
        VALUES (newDATE,
        newMSTHTEMP,
        newMSTHHUM,
        newUTEMP,
        newUV,
        newWSPD,
        newWDIR,
        newWSTEMP,
        newRGC0,
        newRGC1,
        newLC0,
        newLC1,
        newPRS0,
        newTAI8570TEMP);
END IF;
```

END$$

DELIMITER ;

The error I am getting above is:-

SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-th-temp,   ms-th-hum,   utemp,   uv,   wspd,   wdir,   ws-temp,  ' at line 53

It looks more complicated than it really is but if anyone could help point me in the right direction with this, I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a fun problem to solve. What suggestions have you tried, and how have they failed?

Comment: I have tried to use both Ruby and Java to read the data into hash tables / arrays. However, I can't seem to fathom out how to correctly read into ruby hashes when using the DBI module. I get constant errors when trying to access the columns from what I believe is a bug from investigating the issue on various forums. I apologise for not being more specific but I gave up that avenue of approach after I started going red in the face and losing lots of hair.

Comment: Well, without knowing your specific problems, it's hard to offer specific solutions.

Comment: I have tried a heck of a lot of different potential solutions from a lot of different solutions from a lot of different websits and formums. There are too many to mention and indeed I have forgotten nearly all of them but they were obviously not candidates for the job and none of them came close otherwise I would have listed one in my original post. I can program in C and C++ but have forgotten more than I can ramember as I used to do a lot 15/20 years ago. I am not good at MySQL and Ruby and I am literally just learning as I go along.

Comment: I suggest trying one solution--any one you care to try, and then when you run into trouble, ask a _specific_ question about that trouble. That will be much easier for someone to answer than this very open-ended question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change your table definition a tiny bit, so that all fields are null (as in unknown) until they're explicitly filled in. Other than that, use an insert trigger and an update trigger, e.g.:

```
create trigger readings_insert
  after insert on readings
  for each row
begin
  -- upsert into readings2
end;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: This sounds like an interesting solution. So basically it eliminates the need for a cron job.  However I am not too sure how to handle reading the values of each sensor (rows) and inserting them to a single row. Would I need multiple triggers for each row of the readings table?

Comment: Re #1, that's why I suggested to make all fields nullable. That way, you can create the row in readings2 when the first relevant row in readings shows up, and update the row in readings when additional relevant rows are processed. Re #2, I'd write one big query with a huge if/else block that branches based on the name. (Or more appropriately, I'd use ruby to write it for me.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will look into these suggestions. Getting Ruby to write the query for me is way above my head. I will stick to the manual method.... :-)

Comment: The ruby part is less complex that it sounds. Not too sure about MySQL syntax, but in postgresql it would look like this: `cols.each {|col| sql += "if new.name = '#{col}' then ... \n\n"}.join('else') + "\n\nend if;"`.

Comment: I have tried to implement a trigger as per the following code but keep getting a 1064 syntax error. Try as I might, I cannot seem to get past this. Any ideas please?      `delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER test BEFORE INSERT ON readings FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
  SET @t_msthtemp;
  IF readings.name = "MS-TH-TEMP"
   THEN @t_msthtemp = readings.value;
  INSERT INTO readings2 MS-TH-TEMP = @t_msthtemp;
 END;
END$$
delimiter ;`

Comment: This comment formatting is not working for me. Tried everything so apoligies for the unformatted lump of text.

Comment: should `readings.value` et be `new.value` (I haven't written a mysql trigger in a while...)?

Comment: Tried that but it is the same. I also asked for the same problem on another forum and was told that I should hire someone to do it as it is very complex. I don't think it is quite that bad. If only I can sort out this syntax error, I think I might get it cracked. I will keep chipping away at it... :-)